# Invalid write/read valgrind errors, no solution found in other questions

Tags: c, valgrind

I'm writing C code for a homework assignment that replicates main memory by a dynamic array of memory segments.

These memory segments come from a different interface, which is itself just a static array of uint32_ts.

My main memory interface is called heapmem (as in, heap memory), and I've been getting strange valgrind read/write errors since the switch. Before chewing me out, I have looked and researched and am coming to SO as a last resort.

Here's the error

```
==30352== Invalid write of size 8
==30352==    at 0x401661: HeapMem_map (heapmem.c:84)
==30352==    by 0x400E74: map (um.c:109)
==30352==    by 0x4010FD: runOpcode (um.c:182)
==30352==    by 0x4011A1: UM_run (um.c:209)
==30352==    by 0x400A71: main (main.c:10)
==30352==  Address 0x4c53b00 is 0 bytes after a block of size 16 alloc'd
==30352==    at 0x4A0610C: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:195)
==30352==    by 0x401425: HeapMem_new (heapmem.c:32)
==30352==    by 0x400ABE: UM_new (um.c:31)
==30352==    by 0x400A64: main (main.c:8)
==30352== 
==30352== Invalid read of size 8
==30352==    at 0x401787: HeapMem_put (heapmem.c:114)
==30352==    by 0x400D38: sstore (um.c:90)
==30352==    by 0x401090: runOpcode (um.c:167)
==30352==    by 0x4011A1: UM_run (um.c:209)
==30352==    by 0x400A71: main (main.c:10)
==30352==  Address 0x4c53b00 is 0 bytes after a block of size 16 alloc'd
==30352==    at 0x4A0610C: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:195)
==30352==    by 0x401425: HeapMem_new (heapmem.c:32)
==30352==    by 0x400ABE: UM_new (um.c:31)
==30352==    by 0x400A64: main (main.c:8)
==30352== 
==30352== Invalid read of size 8
==30352==    at 0x401956: car_double (heapmem.c:151)
==30352==    by 0x401640: HeapMem_map (heapmem.c:82)
==30352==    by 0x400E74: map (um.c:109)
==30352==    by 0x4010FD: runOpcode (um.c:182)
==30352==    by 0x4011A1: UM_run (um.c:209)
==30352==    by 0x400A71: main (main.c:10)
==30352==  Address 0x4c53b00 is 0 bytes after a block of size 16 alloc'd
==30352==    at 0x4A0610C: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:195)
==30352==    by 0x401425: HeapMem_new (heapmem.c:32)
==30352==    by 0x400ABE: UM_new (um.c:31)
==30352==    by 0x400A64: main (main.c:8)
==30352== 
==30352== Invalid read of size 8
==30352==    at 0x40174A: HeapMem_get (heapmem.c:108)
==30352==    by 0x400CD9: sload (um.c:86)
==30352==    by 0x401079: runOpcode (um.c:164)
==30352==    by 0x4011A1: UM_run (um.c:209)
==30352==    by 0x400A71: main (main.c:10)
==30352==  Address 0x4c7e0f0 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4,096 alloc'd
==30352==    at 0x4A0610C: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:195)
==30352==    by 0x401923: car_double (heapmem.c:148)
==30352==    by 0x401640: HeapMem_map (heapmem.c:82)
==30352==    by 0x400E74: map (um.c:109)
==30352==    by 0x4010FD: runOpcode (um.c:182)
==30352==    by 0x4011A1: UM_run (um.c:209)
==30352==    by 0x400A71: main (main.c:10)
```

Here are functions in code giving me errors:

```
//  Heap Memory Structure
struct T {
   Stack_T SegID_stack;
   MemSeg_T* HeapMem_car;
   int length, highest;
};

//  Create a new heap memory structure
T HeapMem_new (MemSeg_T program) {
    assert (program);
    T retHeap = malloc(sizeof(*retHeap));
    Stack_T structStack = Stack_new ();
    retHeap->length = INIT_SIZE;
    retHeap->highest = 0;
    MemSeg_T* structCar = malloc(INIT_SIZE * sizeof(*structCar));
    //  Fill the array with NULL ptrs
    for (int i = 0; i < INIT_SIZE; i++) {
        structCar[i] = NULL;
    }
    retHeap->HeapMem_car = structCar;
    retHeap->SegID_stack = structStack;
    //  We'll be using the map function to initialize
    //  the heap with a program at the 0th segment.
    HeapMem_map (retHeap, MemSeg_length (program));
    retHeap->HeapMem_car[PROGRAM_LOC] = program;
    return retHeap;
}

//  Line 84
heapmem->HeapMem_car[toMap] = segment;
//  Line 114
MemSeg_T segToPut = heapmem->HeapMem_car[toPut];
//  Line 151
newCar[i] = heapmem->HeapMem_car[i];
//  Line 108
MemSeg_T wordSeg = heapmem->HeapMem_car[toGet];
```

Rest of code available [here](http://pastebin.com/DrgahENB).

Comment: Those aren't types, they're variable names.
int* n = malloc(sizeof(*n)) is the same as = malloc(sizeof(int))

Comment: I don't see anything glaringly wrong with the initial construction construction, assuming Stack_new() returns a valid allocation and all members of retHeap are properly initialized (hard saying without their definitions here as well). The errors in valgrind are telling you this is where the memory was allocated *and* access violated. `map()` and `store()` both seem to be making requests to hit beyond the allocations you made here.

Comment: Putting up the definition now, sorry!

Comment: In your HeapXXXX function family, what guards against out-of-bounds access to the memory held by `heapmem->HeapMem_car[]`? All of the above access violations appear to be centered around faith that indexes into that array are not out-of-bounds, yet valgrind is reporting they *are*. I suggest you slip some `assert()`s into those access points and break on violation to see how you got there.

Comment: But it runs fine, that's the weird part. All of these errors, but it still runs.

Comment: If you don't step outside the allocated memory far - and all addresses are 0 bytes after... - there's a good chance that you don't overwrite vital data and the programme seems to work. Until the allocations land somewhere else suddenly and you step over a page boundary.

Comment: That was it -- write it up as an answer so I can close the question! Thank you so much!

Comment: @DanielFischer who's he referring to, you? or me =)

Comment: @WhozCraig I wondered too. If you haven't written up an answer in an hour or so from our combined contributions, I will. Go ahead and reap the rep.

Comment: @DanielFischer Coming from a guy with 12x my rep, if you think I'm saying no to that, think again =P Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First a small dissection of *one* of your errors:

```
==30352== Invalid write of size 8
==30352==    at 0x401661: HeapMem_map (heapmem.c:84)
==30352==    by 0x400E74: map (um.c:109)
==30352==    by 0x4010FD: runOpcode (um.c:182)
==30352==    by 0x4011A1: UM_run (um.c:209)
==30352==    by 0x400A71: main (main.c:10)
==30352==  Address 0x4c53b00 is 0 bytes after a block of size 16 alloc'd
==30352==    at 0x4A0610C: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:195)
==30352==    by 0x401425: HeapMem_new (heapmem.c:32)
==30352==    by 0x400ABE: UM_new (um.c:31)
==30352==    by 0x400A64: main (main.c:8)
```

Note the bottom of this list is telling you where an allocation *happened*. The top is telling you how it was *misused*. In this case, you're walking past the end of the requested allocation by 8 bytes exactly.

You will notice all of the overruns in this and the remaining violations are reaching beyond their means by exactly the same offset (8 bytes). Further examination of the referenced code shows it seems to always be the *same array*. This is actually a good thing, as it becomes very likely an issue of simply incorrectly calculating how may data items are present and reaching either one or two beyond your allowed space

In this case, the item being breached appears to be a dynamic allocated list of pointers (`heapmem->HeapMem_car[]`). Running on a machine with 64-bit pointers would make each one 8-bytes wide, therefore you're likely simply off-by-one in the last-element-accessible of this allocation, and in C, that generally always means at some point you allocated `N` items and then accessed `array[N]` forgetting the limit is `N-1`. All of the above access violations appear to be centered around faith that indexes into that array are not out-of-bounds, yet valgrind is reporting they are. I suggest you slip some assert()s into those access points and break on violation to see how you got there. Oh wait.. valgrind has that info for you already. Look at that lovely call-stack. Hmmmm...

*So why does it seem to work even with these breaches?* A number of possibilities. If you don't step outside the allocated memory far - and all addresses here are 0 bytes after - (these are pointers after all, so pray they're NULL) there's a good chance that you don't overwrite vital data and the programme seems to work. Until the allocations land somewhere else suddenly and you step over a page boundary. Overshoot that and kerboom.

Thanks to [Daniel Fischer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1011995/daniel-fischer) for contribution on the second part of this answer (why it seems to work).

Comment: _Until the allocations land somewhere else suddenly and you step over a page boundary._ ← That would be the benevolent fail mode. Since this is heap memory, if padding and alignment don't interfere, you'll be overwriting a contiguous chunk of memory. The worst case would be silent corruption of data in that chunk. A more benign case would be a crash later: you overwrite control structures on the contiguous chunk, this may cause a crash if that chunk is freed later (or if that chunk is accessed in any form, e.g: for trying to coalesce adjacent free chunks).